# Why Docker on Virtualbox can't find my DockerFile?

Tags: docker, virtualbox, dockerfile

I'm doing Docker "Get Started" tutorial, at "[Build your own image](http://docs.docker.com/windows/step_four/)".(Windows)

At [Step 3](http://docs.docker.com/windows/step_four/#step-3-build-an-image-from-your-dockerfile) I need to run `docker build -t docker-whale .` while been at my DockerFile folder, but it can't find it.

At my VirtualBox terminal, I go to my DockerFile folder `cd /c/User/username/Desktop/testdocker/` and there it is:
[image: DockerFile is here]

And when I run `docker build -t docker-whale .` at my folder, that's the response:
[image]

What can I do to solve this?
I'm really lost as it is a basic configuration file, and I'm a beginner at VMs and Docker.

And a cookie for a solution about my Docker Quickstart Terminal problem.

> I'm using VirtualBox terminal, because Docker Quickstart Terminal gives me warnings about TLS.
>   Yes, I've changed my BIOS and enabled virtualization.
>   Yes, I've searched for Hyper-v to turn off but there is no Hyper-v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be case sensitive

Try with `Dockerfile`, not `DockerFile`.
Note the lowercase '`f`' in `Dockerfile`.

It would work in your case with `docker build -t docker-whale -f DockerFile .`
(since docker 1.5, and [PR 9707](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/9707))

Comment: It was a case sensitive problem, as you told. Thank you.